# Rails: passing params from one new to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have an Event controller, which I re-direct to from another controllers (Registration)
    (from Registration controller):

```
format.html { redirect_to new_event_path(:event_count => 15) }

(Event controller)

def new
    logger.info params
    @event = Event.new(:event_count => params[:event_count])
    ......

def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

and inside views/events/new.html.erb
<%= f.hidden_field :event_count %>
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following message:

```
unknown attribute: event_count
```

Note that when I check out the log file, from new, I can see that the parameters hash has in it {"event_count":"15"}

Note that event_count is not in my events table. Any suggestions?

## More info

I already have event_count as a virtual attribute in my Event model:

```
attr_accessible :event_count
```

This is a value that is only used during the runtime, and is never stored in the DB. Initially I was using session variables pass this value, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner and safer way to get this done.

## What worked:

I removed the attr_accessor :event_count form my Even model.

In Event Controller:

```
def new
    @event_count = params[:event_count]
    @event = Event.new

def create
    .....
    @event_count = params[:event][:event_count]
```

and in my views/event.html.erb

```
<%= f.hidden.field :event_count, :value => @event_count %>
```

Comment: There's a small error at the end of your post. The hidden_field method is using a period instead of an underscore
`<%= f.hidden_field :event_count, :value => @event_count %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to store `event_count` in your database you obviously have to add it as a column to your events table.

If it is not necessary to store it in the database, you have to add `event_count` as a virtual attribute to your event model. Like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :event_count
  attr_accessible :event_count
end
```

Comment: In my question, I said that event_count is not in my events table. I already have it as a virtual attribute in my event model.

Comment: You *DON'T* have it as a virtual attribute. `attr_accessible` IS NOT the same as `attr_accessor`.

Comment: I used attr_accessor and I got Can't mass-assign protected attributes:event_count

Comment: You have to use both `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`, but I see you solved it by simply storing it in a new instance variable. That's possible too.

Comment: Perhaps I have another issue in my code, but I did add attr_accessor to the existing attr_accessible and still getting errors. I will try that on a clean app to see what happens.

Comment: You have to declare `attr_accessor` before `attr_accessible`. Did you do that? Could you post the code of your event model?

Comment: I was not using that same order, but I do not want to mess with the existing code, so I created a sample and your suggestion works.